# Matlab's 'VariableNames' not accepting mix of numerical & non-numerical entries

Tags: matlab, properties, printf, eval, variable-names

Suppose we have a 1x3 table `A=table(1,2,3);`

whose header names should contain a mix of numericals and non-numericals:

```
A.Properties.VariableNames={'from 1st-5th' 'from 6th-10th' ... 'from 11th-15th'};
```

and generates the following error:

`from 1st-5th' is not a valid variable name.`

I tried the `sprintf` function to solve this error, but the `formatSpec` parameter is confusing. Furthermore, I read about `eval` and would like to know whether it is helpful in my context.

Outcome of `genvarname` use:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error very clearly states, the strings that you have provided for the variable names are [not valid variable names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html#btcg64n) [when they have to be](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html#property_VariableNames)

> Variable names, specified as a cell array of character vectors that are nonempty and distinct. Variable names must be valid MATLAB® variable names

You can use the built-in [`genvarname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) to convert your strings to [valid variable names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html#btcg64n)

```
A.Properties.VariableNames = genvarname({'from 1st-5th' 'from 6th-10th' 'from 11th-15th'});
```

Alternately, come up with your own variable names that are valid variable names (no spaces or hyphens).

```
names = {'from 1st-5th' 'from 6th-10th' 'from 11th-15th'};
A.Properties.VariableNames = regexprep(names, '[ \-]', '_');
```

Comment: thanks, @Suever! Unfortunately this didn't quite produce the desired outcome (see snapshot above)

Comment: @John If the output of `genvarname` doesn't work, then change the labels yourself so that they are what you want them to be (they have to be valid variable names). You can see the links I posted for what defined a valid name

Comment: thanks, @Suever! The work-around solution (e.g. "from_1st_5th") does its job for now, yet I am still looking for the actual outcome in the form as described above

Comment: @John it is not possible since those strings are not valid variable names

Comment: understood, @Suever! Thanks a lot